# PHP MongoDB inconsistent results with query on MongoDate

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm running a very basic script on a sharded MongoDb setup to select the number of messages on a given day.
However, running this multiple times, results in inconsistent results, sometimes it returns the number, sometimes it just returns 0.

The mongodb server has version 2.4.3

Am I missing something here?

This is the script:

```
<?php

$mongo = new MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017");
$db = $mongo->selectDB('database');

$messages = $db->selectCollection('messages');

$date1 = new MongoDate(strtotime('2013-10-20'));
$date2 = new MongoDate(strtotime('2013-10-21'));

var_dump($date1);
var_dump($date2);

$iterator = $messages->find(array('date_replied' => array('$gte' => $date1, '$lt' => $date2)));

$count = $iterator->count();
var_dump($count);
```

And this is the result, 2 times ran directly after each other:

```
~$ php -f mongo.php 
object(MongoDate)#4 (2) {
  ["sec"]=>
  int(1382220000)
  ["usec"]=>
  int(0)
}
object(MongoDate)#5 (2) {
  ["sec"]=>
  int(1382306400)
  ["usec"]=>
  int(0)
}
int(494921)
~$ php -f mongo.php 
object(MongoDate)#4 (2) {
  ["sec"]=>
  int(1382220000)
  ["usec"]=>
  int(0)
}
object(MongoDate)#5 (2) {
  ["sec"]=>
  int(1382306400)
  ["usec"]=>
  int(0)
}
int(0)
```

Comment: Are you targeting reads to secondary members? Also, how is the `database.messages` collection sharded? If you were to connect to the shards individually, run the query on each, and summate the results, does it equal the expected amount?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database might be corrupt. Can you do a db.repairDatabase() and try again? It this fails try to re-create the index, I had similar issues with distributed collections.

Please keep in mind that repairing will block the whole database operations and might throw away any corrupted data. Proceed with care!

Comment: This seems like a premature suggestion. What data corruption are you suspecting that would warrant a full database repair? If actual BSON data was corrupt, we might see exceptions from the server reporting as much (e.g. invalid length, invalid type fields). Given that a sharded cluster is involved, investigating the chunk distribution seems like a more reasonable starting point.